# How to add a column to a link table with code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have a ResearchDatabase entity that has a many-to-many relationship with a Subject entity. i.e. a Research Database belongs in one or more Subject Categories, and a Subject Category contains one or more Research Databases.

In my ResearchDatabaseConfiguration file I have the following mapping:

```
HasMany(rd => rd.Subjects)
                .WithMany(s => s.ResearchDatabases)
                .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.MapLeftKey("DatabaseId");
                        m.MapRightKey("SubjectId");
                        m.ToTable("DatabaseSubjects");
                    });
```

OK, no problem. Works. Creates a link table.

Now I have received a new specification. The ordering of the Research Databases in each subject is going to be split up with the most relevant first (as deemed by a user) in alphabetical order, followed by a second set of 'if you didn't find it, try these also' databases, also in alphabetical order. So, basically, I need another column to signify if the database is in the first or second group. Something like an IsPrimary column, or something like that inside the link table itself. I hope that makes sense.

But, how do I add an extra column to the link table that is created from the above mapping code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. The many-to-many join table is managed internally by Entity Framework and it must only contain the two key columns. You cannot customize this table.

What you need to do is:

- Introduce a new entity into your model which represents the data in the join table (`public class DatabaseSubject` or something). You can customize this entity now as you like, for example add an `IsPrimary` property.
- Remove the many-to-many mapping
- Instead create two one-to-many relationships between `DatabaseSubject` and `ResearchDatabase` (one ResearchDatabase has many DatabaseSubjects) and between `DatabaseSubject` and `Subject` (one Subject has many DatabaseSubjects).

A more detailed description of such a scenario is here: [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table/7053393#7053393)

Comment: Thank you. After more investigation, I was starting to come to the same conclusion. Thanks for providing some steps, and the link to the other post. Now, it is time to do a little refactoring!