# Entity Framework also Linq advice needed

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

i have got on my DB 3 tables
`movies`, `workers`, `workermovies` ( this is the Relationship table )

```
public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        Genres = new List<Genre>();
        Formats = new List<Format>();
        ProductionCompanies = new List<ProductionCompany>();
        Workers = new List<Worker>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string StoryLine { get; set; }
    public int RunTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MPAARateId")]
    public MPAARate MPAARate { get; set; }
    public int MPAARateId { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string OfficialSite { get; set; }
    public int Budget { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Format> Formats { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductionCompany> ProductionCompanies { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
}


public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; } 
    public string Biography { get; set; } 
    public string BornName { get; set; } 
    public double Height { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? Died { get; set; } 
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; } 
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; } 
    public bool IsActor { get; set; }
    public bool IsDirector { get; set; } 
    public bool IsWriter { get; set; } 
    public bool IsProducer { get; set; }
    public bool IsStar { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

in this Relation i got the `movieId` and the `workerId` 
but i also got some more fields  if the person acted or writen or producer etc.

how do i define the `relation entity` class if needed
and when i want to get just the ppl that acted in the movie how do i wrote such a linq
query

Comment: A tip on the side: If you wan't to get just the ppl that acted in the movie, you'll need to change your schema. Because not everyone who is an actor, has acted in all movies they've worked with. (Like Mel Gibson didn't star in Apocalypto, but he directed it...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce an additional entity in your model `WorkerMovie` and convert the many-to-many relationship between `Worker` and `Movie` into two one-to-many relationships - one between `Worker` and `WorkerMovie` and the other between `Movie` and `WorkerMovie`. A sketch:

```
public class WorkerMovie
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }

    public Worker Worker { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }

    public bool WorkedAsActor { get; set; }
    public bool WorkedAsWriter { get; set; }
    public bool WorkedAsProducer { get; set; }
    // etc.
}

public class Movie
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<WorkerMovie> WorkerMovies { get; set; }
    // remove ICollection<Worker> Workers

}

public class Worker
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<WorkerMovie> WorkerMovies { get; set; }
    // remove ICollection<Movie> Movies
}
```

If you want only to find the workers who were actors in a particular movie with a `movieId` you can write:

```
var workersAsActors = context.WorkerMovies
    .Where(wm => wm.MovieId == movieId && wm.WorkedAsActor)
    .Select(wm => wm.Worker)
    .ToList();
```

Here is another answer to a very similar question with many more examples of possible queries: [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table/7053393#7053393)