# Retrieving the value in an association table in Entity Framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I am using `EF 4.1 code first` and I am struggling with the association entity and getting the value that was set in the association table.  I tried to follow the post on: [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table/7053393#7053393).

My tables are as follows (all are in plural form):

Table: Products

```
Id int
Name varchar(50)
```

Table: Specifications

```
Id int
Name varchar(50)
```

Table: ProductSpecifications

```
ProductId int
SpecificationId int
SpecificationValue varchar(50)
```

My related classes:

```
public class Product : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<ProductSpecification> ProductSpecifications { get; set; }
}

public class Specification : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<ProductSpecification> ProductSpecifications { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSpecification
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
     public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
     public virtual Specification Specification { get; set; }
     public string SpecificationValue { get; set; }
}
```

My context class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Specification> Specifications { get; set; }
     public DbSet<ProductSpecification> ProductSpecifications { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
     {
     }
}
```

My repository method where I do my call (not sure if it is correct):

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
     MyContext db = new MyContext();

     public Product GetById(int id)
     {
          var product = db.Products
               .Where(x => x.Id == id)
               .Select(p => new
               {
                    Product = p,
                    Specifications = p.ProductSpecifications.Select(s => s.Specification)
               })
               .SingleOrDefault();

          return null;  // It returns null because I don't know how to return a Product object?
     }
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting back:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ProductSpecification' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
 System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �ProductSpecifications� is based on type �ProductSpecification� that has no keys defined.
```

What does it mean that no keys are defined?  Won't the ProductId and SpecificationId map to Id of Product and Id of Specification respectively?

How would I return a single product with the all the specifications for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework will recognize that `ProductId` is a *foreign key* property for the `Product` navigation property and `SpecificationId` is a *foreign key* property for the `Specification` navigation property. But the exception complains about a missing *primary key* ("Key" = "Primary Key") on your `ProductSpecification` entity. Every entity needs a key property defined. This can happen either by conventions - by a specific naming of the key property - or explicity with data annotations or Fluent API.

Your `ProductSpecification` class doesn't have a property which EF would recognize as a key by convention: No `Id` property and no `ProductSpecificationId` (class name + "Id").

So you must define it explicitely. Defining it with data annotations is shown in the post you linked:

```
public class ProductSpecification
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Specification Specification { get; set; }

    public string SpecificationValue { get; set; }
}
```

And in Fluent API it would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSpecification>()
    .HasKey(ps => new { ps.ProductId, ps.SpecificationId });
```

Both ways define a composite key and each of the parts is a foreign key to the `Product` or `Specification` table at the same time. (You don't need to define the FK properties explicitely because EF recognizes it due to their convention-friendly names.)

You can return a product including all specifications with eager loading for example:

```
var product = db.Products
    .Include(p => p.ProductSpecifications.Select(ps => ps.Specification))
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```