# How do I load related entities from a database view using entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been struggling with a "one to many" relationship regarding a database view.

Im using entity framework and I have this "simplified" model:

A "Course" entity.
A "Student" entity.

A Course can have many Students.

The following code works fine:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
public class Sudent
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}


private List<Course> GetCourses()
{
    List<Course> courses;
    using (var db = context ?? new MyContext())
    {
        courses = (from course in db.Courses select course)
                    .Include(l => l.Students)
                    .ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is my MyContext:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected MyContext()
    {}
    public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OpenCourse> OpenCourses { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view "OpenCourses" that gets all courses that are open.

```
public class OpenCourse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

private List<OpenCourse> GetOpenCourses()
{
    List<Course> courses;
    using (var db = context ?? new MyContext())
    {
        courses = (from course in db.OpenCourses select course)
                    .Include(l => l.Students)
                    .ToList();
    }
}
```

When I run it I get the following inner-exception:
"Invalid column name 'OpenCourse_Id'."

I get that I somehow have to associate the OpenCourse-view with many Students. 
But how?

Prefereably I would like to do this in my method and my lambda expression.

Comment: This association is usually done within the database context object.  Are you able to post the code for `MyContext`?

Comment: Yes. I have seen that. But I have not succeeded. Any ideas on how to how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to override the `OnModelCreating` method of the `MyContext` object.  Entity Framework has some other ways to define relationships on the model itself, but this is unlikely to work with your current setup (multiple entities having a collection of students).

I am assuming that your OpenCourses view is actually a wrapper around your Courses table.  This means I am assuming that Student.CourseId is also your foreign key to OpenCourses.

With that in mind, this is how `OnModelCreating` *might* look

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected MyContext()
    {}
    public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OpenCourse> OpenCourses { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OpenCourse>()
        .HasMany<Student>(p => p.Students)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CourseId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Straight out of the box! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a relation property, from Student to OpenCourse.

You can add it like this.

```
public class Student
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int OpenCourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

But at this time, I think you need to review your domain design.

Also check this for n to m relations.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927380/465536

Comment: hmm.. I do not want to add the property OpenCourseId to the entity Student for the reason to get my view to work.

Comment: I know that my domain design is realy bad in my example. In real life I do not have these entities. Its much more complex.  But thats not the point.   The point is: If i have a database view that returns the same colums as a table, how can I get the relations to work when i refer to that view using entity framework?  Specifically in my example: One to many.