# Is it possible to have a 1:1 and 1:many relationships with a collection only on one side?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

[From reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790470/can-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-5-0-be-configured-keeping-just-one-nav) I believe this is not possible in Entity Framework 5. I am using .NET 8 (pre-release) with whatever version of EF comes with that.

I have the following all Events have 1 Interest and 0...N Tags. They point to a single set of Interests and Tags so deleting an Event should not delete their related Interest & Tags.

And deleting an Interest should set Event.Interest to null and deleting a Tag should remove it from the Event.Tags list.

```
public class Event {
    // lots of properties
    List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    Interest? Interest { get; set; }
}

public class Interest {
    // lots of properties
    // NO public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Tag {
    // lots of properties
    // NO public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

I do not want an `Interest.Events` or `Tag.Events` property because those lists could be 40,000 entries.

Can this be done? Or do I need the matching `List<Event>` properties in the `Interest` and `Tag` classe? And if so, does that need to be public or can it be private?

I tried the following:

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AppUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AppUser> builder)
        builder.HasMany(u => u.Tags)
            .WithMany();
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Interest)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
}
```

But that got me the below error when I delete an Interest object from the database.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> ---- Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Events_Interests_InterestId". The conflict occurred in database "TestHoweInterest_2", table "dbo.Events", column 'InterestId'.

**Update:** I changed to the following and it works. Is this correct?

```
builder.HasOne<Interest>(e => e.Interest)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Interest>("EventId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull) // Or DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull
    .IsRequired(false);
```

**Update 2:** Still a problem. For the call:

```
var listAllInterests = await dbContext.Interests
    .WhereActive()
    .OrderBy(i => i.Name)
    .ToListAsync();
```

I get the error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'EventId'.
```

**Update 3:** Update 2 is still a problem. I can't come up with a way to do this without giving `Interest` a collection of the `Event` objects it is tied to.

Comment: Can you please post a full repro somewhere (like github)?