# Entity Framework 4.2 code first fluent api mapping intermediate table

Tags: entity-framework

How do I setup the mapping for these table relationships using code first and the fluent api?

I have a poco for all three entities created but most people don't have a poco for the "intermediate" table (*PlanUser*) so I couldn't find a good example to go off of. I need to tell EF to map the *PlanUser.PlanCustomerId* column to *Plan.CustomerId* but it either doesn't return the right results OR as in the current setup the mapping for *Plan* throws the error:

> "The specified association foreign key columns 'CustomerId' are
>   invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of
>   primary key columns."

[image]
[image]

```
public class PlanUserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PlanUser>
{
    public PlanUserMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("PlanUser");
        this.HasKey(c => new { c.CustomerId, c.PlanCustomerId });

        this.HasRequired(c => c.Plan).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.HasRequired(c => c.Customer).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class PlanMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Plan>
{
    public PlanMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Plan");
        this.HasKey(c => c.CustomerId);
        // the below line returns only 1 row for any given customer even if there are multiple PlanUser rows for that customer
        //this.HasMany(c => c.PlanUsers).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.PlanCustomerId); 
        // this throws an error
        this.HasMany(c => c.PlanUsers).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("PlanCustomerId").MapRightKey("CustomerId"));
    }
}

public partial class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Customer");
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.HasMany(c => c.PlanUsers).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerId);
    }
}
```

---

@Slauma, sql profiler shows these queries being executed. The second one should include customer id 43 in addition to customer id 1 but it does not. I don't know why its not retrieving that second row.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
[Extent1].[PlanCustomerId] AS [PlanCustomerId], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOnUtc] AS [CreatedOnUtc], 
[Extent1].[IsSelected] AS [IsSelected], 
[Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
[Extent1].[AccessRights] AS [AccessRights]
FROM [dbo].[PlanUser] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CustomerId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=43

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[PlanTypeId] AS [PlanTypeId], 
[Extent1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOnUtc] AS [CreatedOnUtc], 
[Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive]
FROM [dbo].[Plan] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CustomerId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1
```

Here is the C# code that causes the queries to execute:

```
    public List<Plan> GetPlans()
    {
        List<Plan> plans = new List<Plan>();

        // add each plan they have access rights to to the list
        foreach (var accessiblePlan in Customer.PlanUsers)
        {
            plans.Add(accessiblePlan.Plan);
        }

        return plans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Thanks to @Slauma for the help! We are using the repository pattern with IOC(autofac). I shouldn't be calling *Customer.PlanUsers* in my repository service in the first place. Somewhere along the line we started resolving the *Customer* entity using IOC in the repository service to get at certain customer properties quickly and put it in a read-only variable. Inevitably this hosed us because instead of querying the entity repositories themselves we started with the *Customer* entity expecting it to be filled with everything we needed and its not pre-filled.

```
    public List<Plan> GetPlans()
    {
        List<Plan> plans = new List<Plan>();
        var list = _planUserRepository.Table.Where(a => a.CustomerId == Customer.Id).ToList();
        foreach (var planUser in list)
        {
            plans.Add(planUser.Plan);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is actually simpler than the mapping you tried:

```
public class PlanUserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PlanUser>
{
    public PlanUserMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("PlanUser");
        this.HasKey(pu => new { pu.CustomerId, pu.PlanCustomerId });

        this.HasRequired(pu => pu.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.PlanUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(pu => pu.CustomerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasRequired(pu => pu.Plan)
            .WithMany(p => p.PlanUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(pu => pu.PlanCustomerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class PlanMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Plan>
{
    public PlanMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Plan");
        this.HasKey(p => p.CustomerId);
    }
}

public partial class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Customer");
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you disable cascading delete. I probably wouldn't do this (i.e. I would remove the `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` for both relationships) because the association entity `PlanUser` is kind of dependent of the other two entities.

Here are a bit more details about this kind of model (sometimes called "many-to-many relationship with payload"): [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table/7053393#7053393)

Comment: Tried those changes but like the original mapping any given customer returns only 1 PlanUser. My current dataset for customer 43 should be returning 2 PlanUser rows. I used sql profiler and the queries are ignoring the second PlanUser row. I'd like to paste the queries in but this box has a retarded character limit.

Comment: @StrandedPirate: Are all your navigation properties marked as `virtual`, i.e. `Customer.PlanUsers`, `PlanUser.Plan`, etc.?

Comment: Yes they are. Should they not be?

Comment: @StrandedPirate: They should, because your example query relies on lazy loading. Did you try eager loading: `var customer = context.Customers.Include(c => c.PlanUsers).Single(c => c.Id == 43)` and then checked in debugger how many elements `customer.PlanUsers` has?

Comment: This did pull back the two records: var list = planUserRepository.Table.Include(a => a.Plan).Where(a => a.CustomerId == Customer.Id).ToList(); But I still want to know why my mapping setup isn't working. When we call _Customer.PlanUsers_ there is no user-defined linq query behind it, its simply getting all the rows that are available. At this point I've commented out all of the navigation properties, renamed the _Plan.CustomerId_ column to _Plan.PlanCustomerId_, and everything maps correctly but still only 1 row returned for the user.