# Modeling a Many-to-Many relationship with additional field in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have been searching but haven't found anything so far as to a solution for this.

I have 3 conceptual tables:

```
Case
-------------
CaseId
ExternalCaseId


ExtraField
-------------
ExtraFieldId
Name
Type
RegExValidationString


ExtraFieldRef
--------------
Id
CaseId
ExtraFieldId
Value
```

With this, I can dynamically create fields for a form and save the given value.  The trouble I am having is how to create this relationship with EF using the code first model.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin,

I would strongly suggest you search for other posts that have already solved a similar situation. A simple search for me produced this in response to your question: [Create Code First Many to Many With Additional Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

In order that your posts don't get closed or marked down (where-in you lose points), do your self a favor and read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and abide like "The Dude". You will even earn a badge if you complete each section in the FAQ!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, I did search but I guess I wasn't specific enough at the time of the search

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but something like this should work as a starting point on the models:

```
public class Case
{
   public int CaseId {get;set;}
   public virtual Case ExternalCase {get;set;}
}

public class ExtraField
{
   public int ExtraFieldId {get;set;}
   public String Name {get;set;}
   public String Type {get;set;}
   public String RegexValidationString {get;set;}
   public virtual IEnumerable<ExtraFieldRef> ExtraFieldRefs {get;set;}
}

public class ExtraFieldRef
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual Case Case {get; set;}
   public virtual ExtraField {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```