# Multiple many to many inserts

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, many-to-many, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service with oData running and try to insert data into it. I'm trying async from a windows 8 client.

My entity looks like this:

```
Customer 1 -> m CustomerAddress 1 <- m Address
```

I can insert a address or a customer by simply calling the AddObject Method and Save the changes:

```
context.AddObject("Customer",new Customer { FirstName="foo" });
context.AddObject("Address",new Address { Street="bar" });
await context.SaveChangesBatch(); //a extension class that handels the BeginSaveChanges async calls as batch
```

I can also add a relation between Address and Customer

```
Customer customer=new Customer { FirstName="foo" };
Address orderAddress=new Address { Street="bar" };
CustomerAddress customerAddress = new CustomerAddress { Customer = customer, Address = orderAddress };
context.AddObject("Customer",customer);
context.AddObject("Address",orderAddress);
context.AddObject("CustomerAddress",customerAddress);
await context.SaveChangesBatch();
```

But, I **can't** add a second related Address to the context:

```
Address orderAddress=new Address { Street="bar" };
Address deliveryAddress=new Address { Street="bar2" };
CustomerAddress customerAddress = new CustomerAddress { Customer = customer, Address = orderAddress };
Customer customer=new Customer { FirstName="foo" };
CustomerAddress customerAddress = new CustomerAddress { Customer = customer, Address = deliveryAddress };
context.AddObject("Customer",customer);
context.AddObject("Address",orderAddress);
context.AddObject("Address",deliveryAddress);
context.AddObject("CustomerAddress",customerAddress);
context.AddObject("CustomerAddress",customerAddress2);
await context.SaveChangesBatch();
```

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table) I read about that it is enougth to just insert the related entity like this:

```
CustomerAddress customerAddress = new CustomerAddress { Customer = customer, Address = orderAddress };
CustomerAddress2 customerAddress = new CustomerAddress { Customer = customer, Address = deliveryAddress };
context.AddObject("CustomerAddress",customerAddress);
context.AddObject("CustomerAddress",customerAddress2);
await context.SaveChangesBatch(); //On save, it should automatically insert customer and order but it dosn't work :(
```

This would be perfect, but it dosn't work. The error shows a forign key error. Do I have somethind set up wrong? My EF looks like this:

[image: EF Model]

Do I have to add something on the foregin key properties: (I'm using model first approch)
[image]

As a additional node: I'm using Azure SQL Database, so composite keys are not allowed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I am wrong, but the difference is that in the post you referenced, the MemberComments (in your case - CustomerAddress) - is collection:

```
 public virtual ICollection<MemberComment> MemberComments { get; set; }
```

And when adding the items, adding them not to context, but to collection:

> context.**MemberComments**.Add(memberComment1); // will also add member1
>   and comment1 context.**MemberComments**.Add(memberComment2); // will also
>   add comment2

So, in your case, probably, it should be something like

> context.**your_defined_CustomerAddressesList**.add(customerAddress);
>   context.**your_defined_CustomerAddressesList**.add(customerAddress2);