# Many-To-Many Sorting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

ASP.NET MVC4, C#.

I have two models A and B.
They have a many-to-many relationship with each other.

Suppose A has a collection of B. I want to sort the collection of B on A and persist it in a database.

The correct database design for this is to add an additional property to the bridge table A_B.
However, entity framework does not allow this. What is the best solution to allow sorting in entity framework for many-to-many relationships?

Thanks.

Comment: Makes no sense (yet). You don't sort before storing in a Db, you sort when retrieving it with a query.

Comment: You'll have to model it as another entity type in your object model.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591620.aspx#ManyToMany . You can have "bridge table" in EF many to many.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must model this with two one-to-many relationships instead of a single many-to-many. It means that you have to expose the bridge table as an entity in your model and this entity would have a `SortOrder` property:

```
public class A_B
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("A"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AId { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("B"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int BId { get; set; }

    public A A { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }

    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

The entities `A` and `B` get collections not directly to each other but to this intermediate entity:

```
public class A
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<A_B> A_Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<A_B> A_Bs { get; set; }
}
```

To save the relationship "in sorted order" you could then write for example:

```
var b1 = context.Bs.Find(1);
var b2 = context.Bs.Find(2);

var a = new A
{
    A_Bs = new List<A_B>
    {
        new A_B { B = b1, SortOrder = 1 },
        new A_B { B = b2, SortOrder = 2 }
    }
};

context.As.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now, when you load the `A` entity you can load the collection in that sort order:

```
var a = context.As.Find(1);
a.A_Bs = context.Entry(a).Collection(x => x.A_Bs).Query()
    .Include(y => y.B)
    .OrderBy(y => y.SortOrder)
    .ToList();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053393/270591) are more details how to work with such a model that has additional data in the bridge table.