# Change table schema on middle table generated by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have got model with M:N relation like this:

```
[Table("Messages", Schema = "public")]
public class Message
{

    public int Id  { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Phone> Phones{ get; set; }

}

[Table("Phones", Schema = "public")]
public class Phone
{

    public int Id  { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Message> Messages{ get; set; }

}
```

So EF generates middle table for me...
But default schema of table is not public (it is what i need), but still dbo. And gives me error: **schema "dbo" does not exist**.

How can I change table schema of MessagePhone table, without creating MessagePhone model class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is doable. You will have to override OnModelCreating of your DbContext class and configure with fluent API:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasMany<Phone>(m => m.Phones).WithMany(p => p.Messages).Map
           (
            x =>
               {
                  x.ToTable("MessagePhone", "public");
               }
           );
 }
```

You will have to test this, not sure i got all of the syntax right.. Don't have VS here to try it.

Comment: nice effort without VS :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried it like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

Basically you create the middle table yourself, and have many-to-one relationships to it. That way, you can specify anything you like about it. The downside is of course, that you cannot just handle the relation like a collection.