# loop to save clients and contacts ado.net entity model

Tags: c#, datagridview, insert, ado.net, savechanges

'm saving customers this way:

```
tb_clientes tb = new tb_clientes();
tb.clienteNOME = Cliente.clienteNOME;
tb.clienteCNPJ = Cliente.clienteCNPJ;
tb.clienteIE = Cliente.clienteIE;
tb.clienteENDERECO = Cliente.clienteENDERECO;
tb.clienteNUMERO = Cliente.clienteNUMERO;
tb.clienteCOMPLEMENTO = Cliente.clienteCOMPLEMENTO;
tb.clienteBAIRRO = Cliente.clienteBAIRRO;
tb.clienteCIDADE = Cliente.clienteCIDADE;
tb.clienteUF = Cliente.clienteUF;
tb.clienteOBS = Cliente.clienteOBS;
DB DB = new DB();

mydbEntities1 entidade = DB.contexto;
entidade.tb_clientes.Add(tb);
entidade.SaveChanges();
```

I have a contacts table, which will add contacts to a customer. I have to do a foreach in datagridview contacts and insert in the database. How can I do a foreach to save contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understood you question.  Hopefully this helps.
If you need to add multiple clients,

```
tb_clientes tb = new tb_clients();  
entidade.tb_clientes.Add(tb);  
tb = new tb_clients(); //create another  
entidade.tb_clientes.Add(tb); //add the 2nd one  
entidade.SaveChanges(); // you only need to call this once to save all changes.
```

You also mentioned you had a customer and want to add clientes to customer.  You'll have to set the customer otherwise your clientes will remain orphaned.

```
tb.Customer = yourCustomer;
```

If you do the above, and assuming yourCustomer is already in the context, you will not need this line

```
entidade.tb_clientes.Add(tb);
```

Since EF will know what you intended to do and automatically add tb to the context for you.

You can also add clientes directly to the customer

```
tb_clientes tb = new tb_clientes();
yourCustomer.Clients.Add(tb);
tb = new tb_clients(); //create another  
yourCustomer.Clients.Add(tb); //add the 2nd one  
entidade.SaveChanges();
```

Edits in response to OP's comments

From your images, it looks like you are creating a many-many relationship between the tables.
Will your tb_clients_contatos table contain payload in the future?  If not, the easiest thing would be to drop the contato_clientID column and make the remain 2 columns PK.  If you update the EF at this point, it will create a many-many relationship automatically.  You will not have to deal with this table since EF will maintain tb_clients_contatos for you transparently.  Here's the new code

```
tb_clientes tb = new tb_clientes();
yourCustomer.Clients.Add(tb); //you're done at this point.  
    //A row in tb_clients_contatos will automatically be inserted when you SaveChanges.
tb.Customers.Add(yourCustomer); //this will work too.
```

If your relationship tables do need payloads, here's a good post on it.  [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table/7053393#7053393)

Comment: I have to save one customers and many contacts for the same customer. Printscreens that follows will help you understand.

http://s18.postimg.org/uf20ae8ix/foto1.jpg

http://s18.postimg.org/bcn817mw9/foto2.jpg

http://s18.postimg.org/fkdew7yy1/foto3.jpg

Comment: I think it'll be helpful if you can post your code as well.  It's possible you don't even need the loop to save.  Also your model shows many-many or at least 2 1-many relationships.  But your post indicates you just need a 1-many.  Changing the model might work better instead.