# Many-to-Many + additonal column EF design, it is adding an additional column to my table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I want the following table structure:

```
Person
-person_id

Company
-company_id

Company_Person
-person_id
-company_id
-other_column

Location
-id
```

**Currently my EF is resulting in a 'company_id' column in the Person table also as a FK.**

My models look like:

```
public class Person 
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        public int LocationId {get;set;}

        public virtual Location Location {get; set; }           

        public virtual ICollection<CompanyPerson> CompanyPersons {get; set;}
}


public class Company
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CompanyPerson> CompanyPersons {get; set;}
}


[Table("Company_Person")]
public class CompanyPerson
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}


public class Location 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int id {get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons {get;set;}
 }
```

I followed the same pattern as in here: [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

How can I get that extra CompanyId column from being generated in the Person table?

**Update**

Ok I figured it out, and it turns out it was another association that I didn't post (my bad once again).

In my Company model I had this which I commented out and it generated the correct table.  I still want this association so can someone tell me what is why this is happening?

```
public class Company
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CompanyPerson> CompanyPersons {get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<History> Histories {get; set; }
}


public class History
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

So when I commented out the everything in the History model except for the Id property, and the Company.History property it generated the table structure I was expecting.

Comment: It's not also adding a PersonID to Company?

Comment: one second I have to make an edit, forgot about 1 model

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I updated my question with another model in case that is causing some 'confusion' to EF.

Comment: That makes even less sense. There's not even a relationship between this `History` class and `Person`. Keep digging. There's got to be more, as you still don't have any code here that would cause this.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in EF 6.1 ?    Can I add something to the OnModelCreating event to make this more explicit somehow?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Just re-added those properties and bam the extra column is in the Person table again.  It is reproducable...

Comment: @ChrisPratt you were right there was somethign else.  I used the wrong model in the property see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that EF is treating your `CompanyPerson` property as a complex type, because essentially, it can't actually create a M2M relationship with what you've given it. Whether that's actually the problem or not, either way you'll need to fix your `CompanyPerson` properties to be:

```
public virtual ICollection<CompanyPerson> CompanyPersons { get; set; }
```

**UPDATE**

The oddest part is that your `History` class would perfectly explain the issue if it only actually was defined as:

```
public class History : Person
```

That's why I asked you about any subclasses of `Person` because EF's default behavior with inheritance is to use TPH (table per hierarchy). In other words, it will simply add all properties of all subclasses to the base class' table, instead of creating a table for each subclass. Plainly and simply, the only source of this column you aren't expecting is going to be one of either:

1. `Company`, or some subclass of `Company` has direct relationship to `Person` (not through `CompanyPerson`) *and* it's configured to be a one-to-one.
2. `Person` or some subclass of `Person` has a relationship to `Company`.

Comment: Hi Chris, the property does have a 's' at the end, my typo sorry.  I updated my question with another Model (Location) in case that is somehow causing an issue.

Comment: The `s` isn't the important part. The type of `ICollection<CompanyPerson>` is.

Comment: Chris, i'm very very sorry that is what I originally had.  I have fixed that in my Q.  Again, sorry to waste your time on that issue as it was a type and I have that.

Comment: If you already had that, then we're back to there's nothing here that will cause that to happen. There's got to be something else, other than what you've posted, that's interacting with your `Person` class to add that column.

Comment: It seems like EF isnt' looking at the CompanyPerson join table for the Person.CompanyPersons collection.  So then it somehow creates a companyId column in the Person table.  No idea why it is doing this! :)

Comment: It's not doing that. In order for it to add a `companyId` column, it would have to, itself, have a `Company`-type property. Even then, it wouldn't be `companyId`, but `Company_CompanyId` since that's EF's default convention. Are you subclassing `Person` at any point?

Comment: No no subclasses, it is very simple.  See my updates to the question.  still doesnt' make sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, and surprise surprise the real bug was with me!

In my Company table had this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Person> Histories { get; set; }
```

if you didn't catch that, the type should be History and not Person!

```
public virtual ICollection<History> Histories { get; set; }
```

Thanks for all that helped with this!

Comment: Glad you found it. In the future, though, please just copy and paste your code exactly how it exists in your project. We might have been able to catch this from the start if you hadn't been rewriting the code and ironically fixing your mistake at the same time.