# Many to many with additional properties in EF code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I have a many to many relationship between two entities. For simpicity, my entities are

```
class User
{
 int Id;
 string Name;
}

class Roles
{
 int Id;
 string Name;
}
```

I have created linked entity with one additional property to link these as below

```
class UserRole
{
 int Id;
 User user;
 Role role;
 DateTime created;
}
```

I know one way is to create a `List` of `UserRole` in `User` and `Role` entities to achieve a many to many relation. This is very well define on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table).

Here, to get the list of users in a role, you would probably write something like

```
 User.UserRole.Where(r=>r.Role.Id = 1);
```

However I found out that another way is not define this relation between `User` and `Role`, i.e. don't have the `List` of `UserRole` in both entities. To access the related data, you would use the `UserRole` entity.

So to get the list here, you need to do

```
 UserRole.Include(u=>u.User).Include(r=>r.Role).Where(a=>a.Role.Id = 1)
```

***EDIT:***

I like the first way however I am concerned that there are multiple ways to create associations.

1) You can create a `UserRole` with only `User` property set. Then create a new `Role` and add the newly created `UserRole` to the `List<UserRole>` for the `Role`

2) The other way is to create `User` and `Role` (without setting `List<UserRole>` for `Role`). Then you create a `UserRole` and set both `User` and `Role`

I am not sure right way? Should linked entity be navigated for retrieving data?

Comment: I see no reason why *not* to have linked entities in this case.  At the very least they're useful navigation properties.  As a matter of personal preference, I'd recommend starting with `User` or `Role` and navigating from there since those are the aggregate roots (depending on the context) and there would never be a situation of referencing `UserRoles` outside the context of one of those roots.

Comment: @David I agree with having the linked entity. However I am more concerned about the use of linked entity for navigation. Is it just a matter for preference or are there any defined best practices are this?

Comment: Well, the best practice in this regard would likely be to navigate from the aggregate root as well simply as a matter of maintaining the logical business domain.  Why are you concerned about navigating through a property?

Comment: @David I have added more details to question with my concerns. See if it makes sense.

Comment: The first option in the update doesn't make a lot of sense, still thinking from a domain-driven-design point of view.  If the `User` and the `Role` are the models, there logically can't be an association between two of them if those don't don't both first exist.  I still see no reason not to use the navigation properties, rather than pollute the domain by treating every object as an aggregate root.