# ASP.NET MVC Many to Many relationship, using "My Own" table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I am fairly new to using Code First approach with entity framework and I know that I you have a many to many relationship like the entities below, the EF will create the intermediary table automatically:

```
class Post {
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories {get; set;}
  ... 
}

class Category {
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

However, if in the intermediary table I need to have extra data fields, one possible way (which I currently like, maybe because I am unaware of better ways) would be defining a new Entity of my own, like:

```
class Posts_Categories {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int CategoryId {get; set;}
   public int PostId {get; set;}
   public string Exrtafield1 {get; set;}
   public int ex extraField2 {get; set;}
   ...
   public virtual Post Post {get; set;}
   public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

Using this approach, EF does create my custom intermediary table, but it also creates another one of its own called "PostsCategories" which only contains a foreign key to Post_Id and another to Category_Id.

How do I make it not create that extra one and use the one I have defined?
Is this a good way to manage Many to Many relationships with extra data fields??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use one to many relation like this :

```
public class Post
{
    public System.Int32 PostId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Post")]
    public virtual ICollection<Posts_Category> PostCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public System.Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Category")]
    public virtual ICollection<Posts_Category> PostCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Posts_Category
{
    public System.Int32 PostId { get; set; }

    public System.Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    [InverseProperty("PostCategories")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    [InverseProperty("PostCategories")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: wow, @Iraj, I was about to post similar solution, you beat me to it, I agree , this is the way to go , this way it would not create another table, and you can still access all posts from Category and all categories from Post.

Comment: Thanks @Iraj, I will look into it a bit later as first I have to learn the couple new keywords you have used here like the InverseProperty I was unaware of. I may hit you some more questions! Thanks so much Bro!

Comment: @behroozdalvandi: Please see this link may be help you : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I needed to expand a bit on *Iraj*'s answer to make it work. Another modification is that I'm including the default `ApplicationUser` as one of my tables.

So the relation is `ApplicationUser` 1-∞ `IdeaVote` ∞-1 `Idea` (i.e. there are users and ideas, users can vote on ideas, and each vote is represented with a connection between an `ApplicationUser` and an `Idea`.

```
public class Idea
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // This is an ordinary data field
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Idea")]
    public virtual ICollection<IdeaVote> Votes { get; set; }
}

public class IdeaVote
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IdeaId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdeaId")]
    [InverseProperty("Votes")]
    public virtual Idea Idea { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [InverseProperty("Votes")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<IdeaVote> Votes { get; set; }

    // Default stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for it to create that PostsCategories table for the relation between the two, and you are going to want that. If c is a Category, you'll be able to do things like c.Posts

Normally you would not create your own table manually for that. What kinds of data would you be keeping in the "extra" fields? I would probably move the fields to one of the other tables and drop that one. Most many to many relationship tables do not contain extra fields.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I know most of m2m relations don't have extra fields but some do. Just consider a course table, a student tabel, and a StudentCourse table that keep what student has what courses and what is the grade for each course. That grade has to be in an extra field. I would appreciate if you can tell me how I can achieve what I have in mind.

Comment: There is an answer here with 187 upvotes that I believe is exactly what you are trying to do. It's not the easiest thing to accomplish but I hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table

Comment: Thanks Chris, for the useful link :)