# Foreign Key with Fluent API - Code First

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to establish foreign key to 2 classes using FluentAPI and bit confused on the way to implement it.

`ApplicationUser` uses ASP.NET Identity model and has UserId as string

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public virtual List<UserProduct> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

`Product` that has a composite key on columns `ProductID` and `ProductCategoryID`

```
public class Product 
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<UserProduct> Orders { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and another class `UserProduct` that will have many-to-many relationship between `ApplicationUser` and `Product` table

```
public partial class UserProduct
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

The FluentAPI code looks like

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.ProductID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
 modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(x => new { x.ProductID, x.ProductCategoryID  });

 modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>().HasKey(x => new {x.UserId, x.ProductID, x.ProductCategoryID});
```

How do I establish the foreign key relationship of `UserProduct` with `ApplicationUser` and `Product`?

Comment: this link may be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831729/asp-net-mvc-many-to-many-relationship-using-my-own-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the id-property (e.g. OrderId) to the class UserProduct and use this code to connect entities by foreign key.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.User) 
            .WithMany(u => u.Orders) 
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderId);
```