# Entity Framework 6, cascade delete of mapped join table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have simple "graph" representation stored in database. There is `Node` entity which has it's `ID`, `Label` and list of adjacent nodes.

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Node> AdjacentNodes { get; set; }
}
```

Then in `OnModelCreating` on database context class, I have:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasMany(n => n.AdjacentNodes)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(n => n.MapLeftKey("From").MapRightKey("To").ToTable("NodeEdge"));
```

Now, when I want to delete any node which has already any relation, I get constraint error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.NodeEdge_dbo.Nodes_From". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.NodeEdge", column 'From'.
>      The statement has been terminated.

Join table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NodeEdge] (
    [From] INT NOT NULL,
    [To]   INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.NodeEdge] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([From] ASC, [To] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.NodeEdge_dbo.Nodes_From] FOREIGN KEY ([From]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Nodes] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.NodeEdge_dbo.Nodes_To] FOREIGN KEY ([To]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Nodes] ([Id])
);
```

Is there any way how to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` on join table constraints - so it will clear up all references when I'm deleting nodes? (... and keeping model simple without having join table entity)

Comment: Seems that `RemoveRange` helps to avoid constraint error, but still, join table is not cleared despite referenced items are already deleted (... sometimes I have really no idea what EF is doing)

Comment: In fluent api add WillCascadeOnDelete(true)?

Comment: `WillCascadeOnDelete` is not available for many-to-many relation unfortunately.

Comment: see this link maybe helped you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831729/asp-net-mvc-many-to-many-relationship-using-my-own-table/29832776#29832776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the many-to-many association is a self reference, EF chooses to create the foreign keys as not cascading. If it would make both keys cascading there would be a circular cascade, which Sql Server doesn't allow. Apparently, EF doesn't want to choose for you which of both keys should be cascading, so it chooses none.

You can however add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause to the `FK_dbo.NodeEdge_dbo.Nodes_From` foreign key afterwards, or add it in the migration Up method.