# How to define many to many with attributes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I try to model many to many relationship between `Car` and `Employee` where the info about when the car was used are held. So I need a class inbetween which will hold those additional attributes.

The SSCCE:

I have `Person` class:

```
  public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set}; 
  }
```

and a class `Employee` which derives from `Person`:

```
public class Employee : Person {
      public virtual ICollection<EmployeeCar> EmployeeCar { get; set; }
}
```

and a association class`EmployeeCar` which holds attributes `dateFrom`, `dateTo`:

```
public class EmployeeCar {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; } 
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateFrom{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

and finally class `Car`:

```
public class Car {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeCar>  EmployeeCar { get; set; }
    }
```

in `ApplicationDbContext` I hold:

```
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeeCar> EmployeesCars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
```

but when I run the `database-update` I get:

> ```
> MyApp.EmployeeCar: : EntityType 'EmployeeCar' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> EmployeesCars: EntityType: EntitySet 'EmployeesCars' is based on type 'EmployeeCar' that has no keys defined.
> ```

How to fix that situation? How to tell Entity Framework that combination of `Car` and `Employee` is the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the ID properties themselves to the model definition -- EF can add foreign key properties automatically, but it probably doesn't like the idea of seeing navigation properties as keys.

```
public class EmployeeCar {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateFrom{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

[Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

Comment: Unfotunately I got: `The object 'PK_dbo.EmployeeCar' is dependent on column 'EmployeeId'.
The object 'FK_dbo.Person_dbo.EmployeeCar_EmployeeCar_CarId_EmployeeCar_EmployeeId' is dependent on column 'EmployeeId'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN EmployeeId failed because one or more objects access this column.
PM> `

Comment: Automatic migrations? The message makes it sounds like you did have a key at some point

Comment: @yoda: yeah I'm not sure why it would try to drop that column

Comment: I changed the connection name so it deployed new database and it went fine this time. Is this is the shortest way to solve that problem? I mean:  `[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }`?

Comment: For a many-to-many join table like this with additional properties, the only other way I can think of is to use fluent API. This is definitely more concise (though whether it's preferable depends on your design philosophy). I'm not sure if there are other ways