# Storing a collection with multiple same items

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF to store data into a SQL Server database.

There are 2 types of data:

1. Image
2. Symbol

Each symbol contains a collection of images

```
public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

and each image contains a collection of symbols:

```
public virtual ICollection<Symbol> Symbols { get; set; }
```

EF creates a relation-table for the many-to-many relationship.

If a new symbol is created (uploaded) the program looks into the images table if these images are already uploaded.

If yes, the will be added to the images list of the new symbol.

Now there is a symbol with 3 images (all the same!) and it will be added to the `Symbols` table.

But in the relations-table is created ONLY ONE entry!?

So the next time this `Symbol` is read out of the database it just contains only 1 image...

What am I doing wrong?

Or what would be the right way of doing it?

Table structures:

```
[Table("Images")]
public class SqlSymbolImgInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Path { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public String Md5 { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SqlSymbol> Symbols { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Path ?? "x.png").GetHashCode() + Size.GetHashCode() + (Md5 ?? "").GetHashCode();
    }
}

[Table("Symbols")]
public class SqlSymbol
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SqlSymbolImgInfo> Images { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Creating the relation:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SqlSymbol>().HasMany(s => s.Images).WithMany(i => i.Symbols);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Adding the symbols:

1. Add the images if they not exist
2. Get the added images back
3. Add the symbol

   ```
   public void AddSymbol(Symbol sym)
   {
       try
       {
           using (var db = new Db())
           {
               // check if images already exists or add them..
               foreach (var img in sym.Images)
               {
                   var exImg = db.FindImage(img);
                   if (exImg == null)
                   {
                       var newImg = db.Images.Add(img.ConvertToSqlSymbolImgInfo());
                       db.SaveChanges();
                       img.Id = newImg.Id; // get Id of new image
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       img.Id = exImg.Id; // get Id of existing image
                   }
               }

               var sqlSym = sym.ConvertToSqlSymbol();
               // get the existing entries, otherwise the same image will be added again and again...
               sqlSym.Images = sym.Images.Select(i => db.Images.Find(i.Id)).ToList();

               db.Symbols.Add(sqlSym);
               db.SaveChanges();
               sym.Id = sqlSym;
           }
       }
       catch { logIt("error while adding a symbol."); }
   }
   ```

For explanation:

I need to use wrapper classes for the entity framework cause of the `Symbol` and `Image` classes are in a shared library.
And I dont want to include EF in all other projects even if I do not use it there..

Some additional infos:

Symbol with 3 same images:

[image]

Collection after adding and "searching" the image:

[image]

After adding this `Symbol` to the database, take a look at the tables:

`Images` table:

[image]

and the relations table:

[image]

!! the marked line should be there 3 times ?!

Its the `Symbol` with Id 50, which has 3 `Images` with the Id 108 .. NOT just one!

**Here is a simplified project to test it with just a few lines of code:**

[test project](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10782136/efTests.zip.html)

Comment: what's wrong with having *one* image in base, and multiple copies of that image in memory (assuming that what you really want for some reason) ?

Comment: some more details: the Images-Table contains all available Images. And the Symbols just have "links" to the containing Images.. So if there is a Symbol with multiple times the same Image i cant save it at the moment..

Comment: Can you please show us the **table structures** - most importantly the table that contains the many-to-many mapping between symbols and images ....

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Show the code you are using to add the Images to the Symbol

Comment: updated and added some debugging screenshots.

Comment: I "got" the problem.. i tried to add manually a new entry in the relation-table and I got an error! It seems that the PRIMARY_KEY is build over the symbol-id and the image-id. so there can only be one combination of it in this table.. thats bad.. any ideas to "solve" this?

Comment: To show us the table structure please right-click on the table in SSMS and choose command in the popup menu: "Script table - Create To" . Then include the generated script in the question instead of the screenshot of SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote in your comment, the many-to-many relation table has PK defined on both FK keys, so it's impossible to put there same combination twice. I would first consider if this situation should really be possible in your business model. If it should, then one way you can go is manually declaring your intermediate table and giving it artificial PK (just autoincremented int for example).

Then in EF you will have two one-to-many relationships (from `Symbol` and from `Image` to Intermediate table which you can call whatever - like `ImagesInSymbol` or so).
Using these collections will be less convenient but will work. And as a bonus you will be able to set another properties on this relation later (like `DateCreated`, `Status` etc).

For more details see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table).

Comment: thats the way I am currently working on. I thought there must be any way in EF, but unfortunately I have to do it manually.. for more details how to do it, see the link below your answer.