# Entity Framework does not create model entity for many to many tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, many-to-many, datamodel

I have 3 tables: 
**Job**, **Schedules** and **job_schedules** which is the connection table, holding job_id and schedule_id for many to many connection.
I currently use Entity Framework for importing the tables and creating the data model.
The issue i'm facing is that when I import the **job_schedules** table, only a connection between job and schedules is made, no entity is defined in the model. How can I make the import create an entity in the model not just a many to many connection between the two tables?

Comment: Is this code first or database first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you can add the `DbSet` to your `DataContext` manualy.
You'll need the model itself:

```
[Table("tableName")]    
public class JobSchedule()
    {
        //yourproperties with [Column("Name")] atribute
    }
```

And the reference in the DbContext:

```
DbSet<JobSchedule> JobSchedules = new DbSet<JobSchedule>()
```

And my advice is to use Migrations in the future, and the workflow will be much easier.