# Join table in many-to-many with 3-column primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I want to create 3 tables based on 3 entities using code-first and fluent API. I am using Entity Framework version 6. The join table needs a 3-column primary key and additional columns.

My question: how can I use code-first with C# Fluent API to create/map the 3-column primary key for the `PatientTreatment` table? Thank you.

Details of the 3-column primary key for the join table **{ PatentId, TreatmentId , TreatmentDate }**.  The values of `PatentId` and `TreatmentId` are fetched from the other 2 entities (tables) while the value of `TreatmentDate` is entered manually (e.g. C# code or T-SQL script like calling `getdate()` function).

Details of the 3 entities:

```
public class Patient {
  public long PatentId {get; set;} // database created using Identity
  ...
}

public class Treatment {
  public long TreatmentId {get; set;}  // database created using Identity
  ... 
}
```

And the join table (entity)

```
public class PatientTreatment
{
   public long PatentId {get; set;} // part of the primary key from the Patient entity
   public long TreatmentId {get; set;} // part of the primary key from the Treatment entity
   public DateTime TreatmentDate {get; set;} // part of the primary key but its value is from C# code or from T-SQL script, not from other entity (table)
   // other fields ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't model this as a many-to-many association in which the `PatientTreatment` class is hidden, which is what is usually referred to as many-to-many in Entity Framework mapping.

But you didn't intend to do that, as is apparent from the explicit `PatientTreatment` class you show. So it's just a matter of modeling it correctly.

In the `OnModelCreating` override of your `DbContext` subclass, setup the mapping like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<PatientTreatment>()
      .HasKey(x => new { x.PatientId, x.TreatmentId, x.TreatmentDate });
    mb.Entity<Patient>().HasMany(p => p.PatientTreatments)
      .WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.PatientId);
    mb.Entity<Treatment>().HasMany(t => t.PatientTreatments)
      .WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.TreatmentId);

    base.OnModelCreating(mb);
}
```

I think this line `HasKey(x => new { x.PatientId, x.TreatmentId, x.TreatmentDate })` is what you were looking for mainly.

Answer (score 0):

I Just Serch it in stackoverflow

> It's not possible to create a many-to-many relationship with a
>   customized join table. In a many-to-many relationship EF manages the
>   join table internally and hidden. It's a table without an Entity class
>   in your model. To work with such a join table with additional
>   properties you will have to create actually two one-to-many
>   relationships
>   check this [many to many with extra column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)