# Models for a recipe collection(Entity Framework)

Tags: database, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm not sure how to set up this database in Entity Framework.
I have theese models:

```
public class Recipe
    {
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Difficulty { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    }

    public class Ingredient
    {
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

    }
```

But I need to add **measure(unit)** and **amount**. It should be in litre and gram. Where should I add this? My thoughts at the moment are:

- A third entity. But how should i set that up?
- Put it in Ingredient but then I cant reuse the Ingredient on another Recipe

Everything will be displayed in a ASP.NET MVC project later.

Comment: Whenever I've done this, a recipe would include a collection of `Step` classes, each of which can have some instructions (string), one or more ingredients, and amounts (by weight, volume, or number) of those ingredients. You can wrap ingredients if you want into `StepIngredients` or something which can contain an ingredient and an amount.

Comment: See [this article](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/). You would replace CourseInstructor with RecipeIngredient and add properties for measure and amount. Or see [this popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table) about many to many with additional fields.

Comment: Thanks guys. Worked with a third table.