# How to insert data into a table with composite key from Multiple Tables in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys, many-to-many, composite-primary-key

**Answer to this question is found at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)**

Having three tables:

[Database diagram is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMPDz.png)

Book class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class Books
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Books()
    {
        UserBookComments = new HashSet<UserBookComments>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserBookComments> UserBookComments { get; set; }
}
```

User class:

```
public partial class Users
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Users()
    {
        UserBookComments = new HashSet<UserBookComments>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserBookComments> UserBookComments { get; set; }
}
```

And the UserBookComments class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class UserBookComments
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    public int? Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual Bookss Bookss { get; set; }

    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
}
```

The table "Books" is an already saved database. Each user can comment for each book and I want a view model that holds all the data from books with their comments.

The primary key on UserBookComment would be composite, on UserID and BookID.

I used EF Code First and my DBModel context class looks so:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class DbModel : DbContext
{
    public DbModel()
        : base("name=DbModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserBookComments> UserBookComments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Books>()
            .Property(e => e.Category)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Books>()
            .HasMany(e => e.UserBookComments)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Books)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasMany(e => e.UserBookComments)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Users)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

- I wonder how to save comments and display whole list of [title, category, publish date and comments] using a ViewModel class?

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for a method within the `BookEntities` class to insert a record into the `UserBookComment` table?

Comment: @svek yeah, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in the comments, I have provided the way to insert a record into the `UserBookComment` table by adding a method into the `BookEntities` class.

```
public partial class BooksEntities : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserBookComment> UserBookComments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    public void AddComment(int userId, int bookId, string comment)
    {
        var userBookComment = new UserBookComment()
        {
            UserId = userId,
            BookId = bookId,
            Comment = comment
        };

        this.AddComment(userBookComment);
    }

    public void AddComment(UserBookComment userBookComment)
    {
        this.UserBookComment.Add(userBookComment);
        this.UserBookComment.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I assumed based on your provided information that your `UserBookComment` class looked like this

```
public class UserBookComment
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: According to my SQL scripts, the UserBookComment has two other fields as: public virtual Books Books {get;set;} ---
 public virtual Users Users {get; set;}

Comment: @Joey - It would be best for you to provide the class in your question. However, this answer should be sufficient in regards to creating a record in the requested table, no?

Comment: I could configure the many-many relationship by using code first EF, and I totally updated my question. Any comments?

Comment: Your question is now completely different!!! Obviously, my answer will not apply now... I can understand that you changed your mind, but the community won't appreciate it when a question does a 180. You should have opened up a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using entity framework. To create a composite key, just at the Key attribute on both properties. To control the key order use the column atribute. Referencing should be fixed automaticly using the names in the model, or try googling on entity framework foreign key. I'm sorry I don't have the link right now.

For the viewmodel, just don't foget to use include in the statement.