# How to solve Code First from database many-to-many mapping in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, ef-code-first-mapping

Bellow code snippet showing my scenario:

```
[Table("User")]
public partial class UserModel
{
 public UserModel()
 {
    UserRole = new HashSet<UserRoleModel>();
 }

  public int UserID { get; set; }
  public string FullName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<UserRoleModel> UserRole { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserRole")]
public partial class UserRoleModel
{
    public UserRoleModel()
    {
            User = new HashSet<UserModel>();
    }

   public int RoleID { get; set; }
   public string RoleName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<UserModel> User { get; set; }

}
```

Now within `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` **EF** Generate code like bellow

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>()
                .HasMany(e => e.UserRole)
                .WithMany(e => e.User)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("UserRoleMapping").MapLeftKey("UserID").MapRightKey("UserRoleID"));
```

now this is fine **add / insert** data into `UserRoleMapping` table. But how to

> Get / Update data from UserRoleMapping table ?

I try to solve this issue following [create-code-first-many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) the post and come-up with third class with `join entity`

```
 public partial class UserRoleMappingModel
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public UserModel User { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public UserRoleModel UserRole { get; set; }
    }
```

then add `public virtual ICollection<UserRoleMappingModel> UserRoleMapping { get; set; }` in both the `UserModel` and `UserRoleModel` class

But when I try to GET value from database using bellow code

```
var results = _userRepository.GetAll()
                 .Include(r => r.UserRoleMapping
                 .Select(s => s.UserRole))
                 .SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
```

It throws **ERROR**

> "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoleMappingModel'.\r\n

Even I tried bellow Configuration within `OnModelCreating`, but nothing work as expected

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleMappingModel>()
 .HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });
```

Comment: When you introduce a junction class (`UserRoleMappingModel`) you should remove the many-to-many mapping and add two 1:n mappings.

Comment: And why to you want to have the mapping table in your model?  It's fine to do, but it's sometimes inconvenient to have to traverse the mapping table in code.

Comment: @How to get value from Mapping Table without using `Mapping Model` ?

Comment: @GertArnold: are you talking to remove `.Map(m => m.ToTable("UserRoleMapping").MapLeftKey("UserID").MapRightKey("UserRoleID"));` this ?

Comment: No, the entire `HasMany-WithMany` mapping.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Without `MappingModel` how to get value from mapping table ?

Comment: You usually don't need to directly access the linking table, and so EF leaves it out of your entity model, by default.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: But I need to acess that table, let say I want to Update `User Role ID` how can I do it without Mapping model ? Is their any other way !!

Comment: You use the Navigation Properties.  You add or remove a User from a Role, or a Role from a User.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Will you please provide a code snippet, for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS per `GertArnold` response I solve the issue in bellow way.

**1st Remove below settings**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>()
                .HasMany(e => e.UserRole)
                .WithMany(e => e.User)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("UserRoleMapping").MapLeftKey("UserID").MapRightKey("UserRoleID"));
```

**2nd Add bellow settings**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleMappingModel>()
 .HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });
```

**3rd add table property in Mapping Model**

```
[Table("UserRoleMapping")]
public partial class UserRoleMappingModel
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public UserModel User { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public UserRoleModel UserRole { get; set; }
    }
```

**4th Create a Mapping Repository**

```
IUserRoleMappingRepository
```

**5th a simple get Method (Problem Solved)**

```
var results = _userRoleMappingRepository.SearchFor(e => e.UserId == id)
                                                            .Select(s => new
                                                            {
                                                                s.UserId,
                                                                s.UserRoleId,
                                                                s.UserRole.RoleName
                                                            })
                                                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Point to be noted :** using bellow query I able to get result but unable to serialize with `Newtonsoft.Json` due to self referencing issue

```
var results = _userRepository.GetAll()
                 .Include(r => r.UserRoleMapping
                 .Select(s => s.UserRole))
                 .SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
```

Try bellow `JsonSerializerSettingssetting` alternatively but unable to serialize sucessfully

```
PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All / Object
ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize / Ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `UserRoleMappingModel` has no Table-Attribute. Bcause of this, EF searches for a Table `UserRoleMappingModel` instead von `UserRoleMapping`.

You have to choose: Either map the n-to-n relationship and don't access the mapping-table or load the table to access the values in it.

As workaround you could implement a Not-Mapped column:

```
[Table("User")]
public partial class UserModel
{
    public UserModel()
    {
        UserRole = new HashSet<UserRoleModel>();
    }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleMappingModel> Mappings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleModel> UserRole
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Mappings.Select(s => s.UserRole);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't write a Mapping- Model then how to get value from Mapping table ?   If put `Table-Attribute` throw error duplicate schema.

Comment: Correct. You can use any table only once. If you need the values of mapping-table, you can't map "n-n" you have to do "1-n-1". Example: you have to access the roles of you user this way: `myUserModel.Mapping.UserRole`