# Entity Framework - adding to auto generated table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on a code first .NET application that has an auto generated table. I created my `Order` class, with a link to `Item`. Instead of manually creating an `OrderItem` class, I simply used `List<Item>` and it auto generated the `OrderItem` table for me;

```
[Table("Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }      

}
```

This, as expected has made a table in the database called `OrderItems`

Many years later, we now want to reference `OrderItems` from another table within entity framework. However, as it is not a class we can physically reference, we are not sure how to do it in code. Obviously changing the database is easy, but that won't help for code first.

I'd like to do something like the following

```
[Table("AnotherTable")]
public class AnotherTable
{
    [Key]
    public int AnotherTableId { get; set; }

    public string SomethingHere { get; set; }     

    public virtual OrderItem OrderItem { get; set; } 

}
```

Which I cannot do, as `OrderItem` isn't a class it understands.

Is my only alternative to try and recreate in code, what EF auto created for me? I.e

```
[Table("OrderItems")]
public class OrderItem
{   
    public virtual Order Order_OrderId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Item Item_ItemId { get; set; } 

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have tried to add more explanation

Comment: *Is my only alternative to (...)?* Yes.

Comment: @GertArnold well theres the answer I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: Note that both `Order` and `Item` will now need `ICollection<OrderItem>` instead of their current collections, so the querying will be different too. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053393/861716).