# Fluent API One to Many relation with static table

Tags: sql, entity-framework, dbcontext, fluent, ef-fluent-api

I need help.
I have three static table (Dictionary of Country, Region and Cities). I set this tables in my Initilizer class.
I need to create One to Many  relation with my own User table without created Foregion Key in dictionaries tables by Fluent API.

Dictionary Tables (Countries, Regions and Cities):

[image]

My User table:

```cs
public class UserWorker
{
  public UserWorker()
    {
        Countries = new List<DCountry>();
        Regions = new List<DRegion>();
        Cities = new List<DCity>();
        Professions = new List<DProfession>();
    }

    public int UserWorkerId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DCountry> Countries { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DRegion> Regions { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DCity> Cities { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DProfession> Professions { get; set; }
}
```

**How I can add relation without UserWorker_UserWorkerId ?**

P.S: I have another two my own table that need to connect by the same relation One to Many by Fluent API.

I don't understand how i can add Objects dictionary lists to my own table without create virtual foregion key in my static table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a single user can have many cities, and the same city can be assigned to many users, this is a many-to-many relationship.

You can configure this in the ModelBuilder as follows:

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<UserWorker>()
   .HasMany(u => u.Cities)
   .WithMany()
   .Map(x => {
        x.MapLeftKey("UserWorkerId");
        x.MapRightKey("CityId");
        x.ToTable("UserWorkerToCityMap");
   });
```

EF will create an additional table `UserWorkerToCityMap` for this relationship that has two columns with foreign key references to `UserWorkerId` and `CityId`. No additional foreign key column will be added to DCity.

[Configure Many-to-Many Relationship in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I considered this option but if I have User table and another table  that will have the same relation? User with --> Cities, Countries, Regions and EnotherTable --> with cities, Countries, Region? Than I need two table Many to Many?

Comment: No problem, just create the relationship twice with different names for the mapping tables , e.g. `UserWorkerToCityMap` and `OtherToCityMap`

Comment: Than I will have 6 Map Tables: 3 map table for User (UserToCityMap, UserToRegionMap, UserToCountriesMap) and 3 map table foth enother own table. Correctly?

Comment: Yes exactly. But these tables will not take up much space because they only contain foreign keys.

Comment: Ok. I understand. But is there a way to have one table for relation User with Dictionary static table (Contries, Region and Cities)? One table Map for three relation?

Comment: You could model the join table and use two one-to-many relationships instead of one many-to-many (many-to-many will always be managed by EF internally). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053393/1450855

Comment: The Map() method does not appear to exist anymore.