# Entity Framework: The Entity with schema was already defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my database, I have two tables, namely `Book` and `User`, that have a M-to-M relationship table named `BookXUser`. In the relationship table, there are two fields, which are the foreign keys of the `Book` and `User`, and another field named `bookShelf`. Since using only Entity Framework I couldn't find a way to insert a M-to-M relationship while inserting into the `bookShelf` at the same time, I decided to make a model for the relationship table, which are defined like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasMany<UserData>(s => s.user)
            .WithMany(c => c.book)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("bookID");
                cs.MapRightKey("userID");
                cs.ToTable("BookXUser");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<BookXUser>()
            .HasRequired<UserData>(s => s.user)
            .WithMany(g => g.bookXuser)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.userID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BookXUser>()
            .HasRequired<Book>(s => s.book)
            .WithMany(g => g.bookXuser)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.bookID);
```

The problems arrive when I execute the following line:

```
userDataRepo.FindBy(user => user.email == entry.email).FirstOrDefault()

The EntitySet 'BookUserData' with schema 'dbo' and table 'BookXUser' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.
```

How can I solve this error while keeping the relationship table as a model which references the `BookXUser`? The idea is that I am using lazy loading on the virtual methods found in the model of BookXUser so I can get my books and users more easily, and I also manually insert my data in it so I can populate the bookshelf field.

```
public class BookXUser : IEntityBase
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int bookID { get; set; }
    public virtual Book book { get; set; }
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserData user { get; set; }
    public string bookShelf { get; set; }
}
```

The `Book` entity

```
public class Book : IEntityBase
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string isbn { get; set; }
        public int noPage { get; set; }
        public string edition { get; set; }
        public string bLanguage { get; set; }
        public byte[] bookPic { get; set; }
        public string publisherSite { get; set; }
        public string bookFormat { get; set; }
        public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime initialReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string publisher { get; set; }
        public string overview { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Author> author { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Genre> genre { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserData> user { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Rating> rating { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Review> review { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BookXUser> bookXuser { get; set; }

        public Book()
        {
            this.author = new HashSet<Author>();
            this.genre = new HashSet<Genre>();
            this.user = new HashSet<UserData>();
            this.rating = new HashSet<Rating>();
            this.review = new HashSet<Review>();
            this.bookXuser = new HashSet<BookXUser>();
        }
    }
```

The `UserData` enity

```
public class UserData : IEntityBase
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string userpass { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public byte[] userPic { get; set; }
        public string userOverview { get; set; }
        public DateTime joinedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Book> book { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Review> review { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Rating> rating { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserData> user { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BookXUser> bookXuser { get; set; }

        public UserData()
        {
            this.book = new HashSet<Book>();
            this.review = new HashSet<Review>();
            this.rating = new HashSet<Rating>();
            this.user = new HashSet<UserData>();
            this.bookXuser = new HashSet<BookXUser>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: BTW in your sample code you've duplicated `modelBuilder.Entity<BookXUser>()[...]` two times.

Comment: My mistake, I copied the code wrong. Fixed now. (I still have the error)

Comment: Can you show us the Book and UserData entities in your question.

Comment: found an answer here which might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined your `Book` and `UserData` entities in a wrong way. As you say in your question you are trying to define a many-to-many relashionship between `Book` and `UserData` so you added a join entity `BookXUser` because that entity hold a data `BookShelf`. That join entity will use by convention `BookXUser` as a table name.

Also, you defined two collections:

- `ICollection<UserData> user` in your `Book` entity
- `ICollection<Book> book` in your `UserData` entity

You also use this fluent configuration in your `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasMany<UserData>(s => s.user)
    .WithMany(c => c.book)
    .Map(cs =>
    {
        cs.MapLeftKey("bookID");
        cs.MapRightKey("userID");
        cs.ToTable("BookXUser"); // <-- this is your error.
    });
```

Doing it like this, you're adding another many-to-many relashionship between `Book` and `UserData` and use `BookXUser` as the name for the join table which is already used by your entity `BookXUser` you've created.

To solve your issue you don't need to add the collections and to configure many-to-many relationship fluently like you did. Why? Bacause you have an join entity `BookXUser`.

So :

- remove `ICollection<UserData> user` from your `Book` entity and replace it with `ICollection<BookXUser> BookXUser`
- remove `ICollection<Book> book` from your `UserData` entity and replace it with `ICollection<BookXUser> BookXUser`
- remove the fluent configuration you added for many-to-many relashionship between `UserData` and `Book`.

Comment: After modifying some methods and replacing everything with your suggestion, the error disappeared. Thank you so much :).